# conectar a Servidor MySQL mediante privateKey

Tags: mysql, c#, ssh

Estoy intentando acceder a un servidor de mysql mediante c#. Los datos de conexión y credenciales son correctos ya que puedo connectar mediante gestor de base de datos.
Agradecería vuestra ayuda

```
privateKeyLocation = @"C:\rutafichero\ssh1";
var sshServer = "155.90.155.90";
var sshUserName = "usuario_ssh";
var sshPassword = "";
var databaseServer = "10.0.0.9";
var databaseUserName = "usuariob_bdd";
var databasePassword = "clave_bbdd";

var pk = new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyLocation);
var keyFiles = new[] { pk };
var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName, keyFiles));
var con = new ConnectionInfo(sshServer, 3306, sshUserName, methods.ToArray());

using (var sshClient = new SshClient(con)){
     sshClient.Connect();
     string connectionString = "datasource=10.0.0.9;port=3306;username=databaseUserName;password=databasePassword ;database=project;";

     string query = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
     MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
     MySqlCommand commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
     commandDatabase.CommandTimeout = 60;
     MySqlDataReader reader;


}
```

Comment: Explica mejor tu pregunta, no se entiende si lo que quieres es conectarte a traves de un tunel ssh o pivotar en una maquina via ssh y abrir una conexion mysql a una tercera maquina

Comment: Hola, queria acceder al servidor de mysql mediante tunel ssh

Answer (score 0):

al final he ido por aqui

```
ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(sshServer, 22, sshUserName,
                new AuthenticationMethod[]{

                new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName,new PrivateKeyFile[]{
                    new PrivateKeyFile(@"rutaclave","")
                }),
                }
            );
```

espero que pueda serveir a quien lo necesite

Gracias